# Problem in URL validation using ASP.Net Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to use the ASP.Net Regular Expression Validator to validate a URL field. URL is `www.tachibana.co.jp/tokyosys.htm`. Validation expression used is `ValidationExpression="http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?"` but this is not working. Is there anything wrong with the Regular expression or URL ?

Rules are as below.

1. It should validate even if (http or
   https) is included or not.
2. It should also trim the URL before
   validating.
3. It should also validate the sub
   domain URL's
4. It should also validate the URL's to
   a file on domain or sub domain.

thanks

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - It should ignore any extra space before and after the url if there is any.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your regex

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?
```

expects the URL to start with `http://` or `https://`. Also, the dash inside the character class is misplaced.

Edit: Now that you've posted your rules, I suggest this:

```
^\s*((?:https?://)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+)(/[\w ./?%&=-]*)?\s*$
```

After a successful match, group 1 will contain the domain, and group 2 will contain the file path, if present.

Comment: I tried it by adding http or https but still fails. URL may contain any number of dots and this may be a url to file on server (as in question) or url of the default page like http://www.msn.com

Comment: the 2nd one fails to validate if i only provide msn.com in text box.

Comment: @Umar: Well, what are your rules for validating a URL? You can use `(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w ./?%&=-]*)?` but that will probably allow stuff you don't want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?i)(http|ftp|https)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$
```

Comment: @Pankaj: thanks - First one is working but its CASE SENSITIVE. Also invalidate the url if there is any single space at the end.

Comment: whole url should be case insensitive. HTTP://www.msn.com will be invalid against the given expression. It should also trim the extra space if there is any.

Comment: These expressions aren't what you need; they incorrectly limit top-level domains to 2 or 3 characters (what about .mobi or .info?), and don't seem to even try to allow for file names at all.

Comment: I never save a website shows the url starts with HTTP://www.msn.com      instead it should be like http://www.msn.com for that us can use ^(http|ftp|https)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?$

Comment: @Umar - I wouldn't try to use Pankaj's answer; he does not appear to have read your question. His expression will not allow file names to be included in a URL. It doesn't even try to.

Answer (score 0):

```
"(http(s)?://)?([\www]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /(http(s)?:\\)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com|.in|.org]+(\[\?%&=]*)?/
if (re.test(txt)) {
alert('Valid URL')
}
```

you can add domain needed in the last field of com,in,org